# ParsleyJS - Localization with data-parsley-`constraint`-message

Tags: javascript, localization, parsley.js

Currently I'm using

```
data-parsley-`constraint`-message="English sentence goes here"
```

but now that I'm working to add localization these messages will never be translated using the i18n library because they are custom.

Is there a way to add something like

```
data-parsley-`constraint`-message-fr="Francais francais francais"
```

or someway to do it through JS?

Specifically I'm using data-parsley-required-message=""

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't you use the localization of Parsley instead of defining the messages on the inputs?

I suggest you download the localizations that you need [from the source](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/tree/master/src/i18n). After that, [according to the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-localization) you can load the i18n before the plugin, like this:

```
<script src="i18n/fr.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/it.js"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('fr');
</script>
```

Or you can load the i18n after the plugin (in that case, it will assume the last loaded localization - in the following example it will be Italian), like this:

```
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/fr.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/it.js"></script>
```

On my projects I typically load the needed localization based a Cookie or Session variable:

```
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="i18n/"<?= echo $lang ?>".js"></script>
```

With either of the options, you don't need to add **data-parsley-`constraint`-message** to each input. And when you need to change a message you can do that in the localization file.

To conclude, if you need custom validators, you can check [the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-craft) to see how you can define the different localizations.

---

## UPDATE

<sub>**This solves the OP's need by changing the source code of the plugin**</sub>

You can edit in your *parsley.js* a method called `_getErrorMessage` (line 1264 with 2.0.4), which looks like this:

```
_getErrorMessage: function (fieldInstance, constraint) {
    var customConstraintErrorMessage = constraint.name + 'Message';
    if ('undefined' !== typeof fieldInstance.options[customConstraintErrorMessage])
        return window.ParsleyValidator.formatMessage(fieldInstance.options[customConstraintErrorMessage], constraint.requirements);
    return window.ParsleyValidator.getErrorMessage(constraint);
},
```

To something like this:

```
_getErrorMessage: function (fieldInstance, constraint) {
    //added
    var locale = window.ParsleyValidator.locale;
    var namespace = fieldInstance.options.namespace;
    var customConstraintErrorMessage = namespace  + constraint.name + '-' + locale;

    if (fieldInstance.$element.attr(customConstraintErrorMessage)) {
        // treat parameters
        if (fieldInstance.$element.attr(customConstraintErrorMessage).indexOf("%s") !== -1)
            return window.ParsleyValidator.formatMessage(fieldInstance.$element.attr(customConstraintErrorMessage), constraint.requirements);
        return fieldInstance.$element.attr(customConstraintErrorMessage);
    }

    // original
    var customConstraintErrorMessage = constraint.name + 'Message';
    if ('undefined' !== typeof fieldInstance.options[customConstraintErrorMessage])
        return window.ParsleyValidator.formatMessage(fieldInstance.options[customConstraintErrorMessage], constraint.requirements);
    return window.ParsleyValidator.getErrorMessage(constraint);
},
```

With this, you can specify the messages directly in the input, using the sintax **data-parsley-`constraint`-`locale`**. Here is a sample:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" data-parsley-required="true"
    data-parsley-required-en="Name is required"
    data-parsley-required-pt="O nome é obrigatório" />
<input type="number" name="phone" value=""
    data-parsley-minlength="9"
    data-parsley-minlength-en="Phone length must be equal to %s"
    data-parsley-minlength-pt="O telefone deverá ter %s digitos" />
```

When you need to use some kind of constrains (in the above example, there is `data-parsley-minlength` which is variable) you can use the `%s` inside the message. This will be replaced for the correct value.

Just before you bind parsley to your form, you need to set the locale you want to use (beware: you need to include the javascript file relative to the locale that you are using, otherwise you will get an error like `Error: pt is not available in the catalog`):

```
window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('pt');
$("#myForm").parsley();
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/062kf8te/) for demonstration. If you want to test, just `setLocale('en')` and see the messages in English.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to define custom error messages for each input, rather than having a generic error message for the "required" field.
But it looks like to do that I will need to make custom validators for each input field.

Comment: I understand what you need. To this date, Parsley doesn't have anything that solves your issue. If you tweak the source code you might get something to work, but I guess it would be better if you send a pull request to [github](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pulls).

Comment: I've put in a feature request. We'll see if the maintainers give it any thought. *fingers crossed* But for now I'll probably just use the standard messages and be sad that I can't customize them.

Comment: If this is really important to you, I've managed to change the source code so it works as you need. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only put -message after your attribute of parsley which is you used for validation.

for example,

```
  <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Enter confirm password" data-parsley-equalto="#password"
                           data-parsley-equalto-message="This value should be the same as password"
                           required>
```

> data-parsley-equalto is my parsley validator then after for custome message show for that equalto i simple put -message after that.
>   `data-parsley-equalto` >> `data-parsley-equalto-message`